# Stop a long running operator with escape?

Tags: python, operator

Would it be possible to write an operator that would allow the user to interrupt it with the escape key or even when a value gets changed in the redo pannel? Any pointer about how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with modal operator (you can find example [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html), look for 'Modal Execution'). I'm not sure about redo panel but executing some function on Redo can be done with handlers `bpy.app.handlers.redo_pre` or `bpy.app.handlers.redo_post`. Just append your cancelling function to them, like this:

```
import bpy

def my_func(self, context): # must have 2 arguments (3 if called from class)
    print('Got Redo!')

bpy.app.handlers.redo_pre.append(my_func)
```

It will be executed on each redo. Use `bpy.app.handlers.redo_pre.remove(my_func)` to remove redo handler or `bpy.app.handlers.redo_pre.clear()` to clear all redo handlers

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Are there not a way to check if a key is down or something. Making it Modal is just a bit too overkill maybe?

Comment: I don't think there is another option because the idea of the modal operator seems to be exactly in serving as a listener to the user commands (keyboard, mouse, etc). It can run in the background, you just need to return `{'PASS_THROUGH'} ` in the `modal()` method instead of `{'RUNNING_MODAL'}`. In this way, as I know, it doesn't freeze other operators and waits until some event which you defined in the `modal()` method happens. Or I guess it can also check some value. By the way, the full list of events references [you can find here.](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Event.html)